# Datatables sorting in Jquery Datatables

Tags: sorting, filter, datatables

I'm using a Jquery DataTable with filter and sorting. I use a custom filter search on the header of the table. The problem is that the sort row are included in the search input instead of in the table header ... How can I set the sort on the header ??

```
   $('#ticketList thead th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
        if(title !== "dati" && title !== "immagini"){
            $(this).html( '<input class="mdl-textfield__input" placeholder="Ricerca '+title+'" />' );
        }else{
            $(this).html( '<input class="mdl-textfield__input" style="margin-bottom:10px" class="mdl-textfield__input" placeholder="Ricerca '+title+'" />' );
        }
} );

// DataTable
var table = $('#ticketList').DataTable( {
    "orderCellsTop": true,
     "bSortCellsTop": false,
    "scrollY":     "300px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "columns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "orderable": false },
        { "orderable": false }
      ]
} );

// Apply the search
   table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
     that
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
  }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This live [example](http://live.datatables.net/gepatita/1/edit) shows what you need to do. It creates a row above the column header for the input elements, keeping the original header there for the sorting.

In summary, have a double header in the HTML:

```
    <thead>
      <tr id="filterboxrow">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>          
    </thead>
```

Then in the JS, modify the top one:

```
    $('#example thead tr#filterboxrow th').each(function() {
      var title = $('#example thead tr#filterboxrow th').eq($(this).index()).text();

      $(this).html('<input id="input' + $(this).index() + '" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="filter by ' + title + '" />')
        .css('padding-left', '4px');
      $(this).on('keyup change', function() {
        table.column($(this).index()).search($('#input' + $(this).index()).val()).draw();
    })
```

Comment: I have a complex header, your solution replecate che search filter on the bottom of the header...